# Javascript : Strange behaviour `empty string` AND `false` returns empty string

Tags: javascript

Today I came across the strange behaviour in Javascript. Below is the code

```
return "" && false
```

returns  "".

Why it behaves so ?

Comment: `falsy1 && falsy2` returns `falsy1` - lazy evaluation.

Comment: because `Boolean("") === false`

Comment: I already knew this concept of lazy evaluation, but I thought  all comparison expression will return boolean value only. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

> The production LogicalANDExpression : LogicalANDExpression && BitwiseORExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LogicalANDExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. If ToBoolean(lval) is false, return lval.
> 4. Let rref be the result of evaluating BitwiseORExpression.
> 5. Return GetValue(rref).

[ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11)

This means:

> Return the first value if it is falsy, return the second value if the first is truthy.

---

This is also the behavior seen if you do:

```
return false && true
```

You get `false`.

This means also that this

```
return 23 && "Hello"
```

would give you "Hello"

Comment: just want to add that because of such behavior it's possible to easily assign default value to function parameter in case it was not passed, like this: ```function setName(name) { name = name || "default name"; }```

Comment: @tytyryty While this is naturally possible, ES6 provides us a much cleaner way to do this: `function setName(name = "default name") { ...`. But for non-ES6 you’re right, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The LHS is run first and the return exits you from the function